# Package installation error Missing organization features: CustomerSuccescPortal

Tags: community-builder, experience-builder-page

I faced an issue while installing  the package.The package I created consists of customer portal and partner portal.

Error while installing the package:

This package can't be installed.
There are problems that prevents this package from being installed.

**Missing organization features: CustomerSuccescPortal**

Answer (score 0):

Because your package contains portals, those features need to be turned on in the target org before the package can be deployed in to it.

When you create a package the UI (or the CLI for 2GP) shows a list of features that the package requires because of what's included in it, and if those aren't enabled in the target org then the package can't be installed there until they are. You'll see similar issues if your code depends on multi-currency or person accounts for example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the Customer Portal being enabled in your org or not. You can check this by following the click path below:

Setup | Customize | Customer Portal

You can then EDIT and enable it if necessary.

Whether the package you are trying to install requires the Customer Portal enabled beforehand, I suggest you ask this from the developer(s) of the app.

If the Customer Portal enabled for your org then check the below.

Can you remove the references to the following user fields from your package will resolve the issue.

1. IsPortalEnabled
2. IsPortalSelfRegistered
3. PortalRole